# how to replace database value by update table php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created two tables subscription_pending and subscription_complete

subscription_complete contain

```
id mag1 mag2 mag3 mag4
4  100  0    100  0
```

subscription_pending contain

```
id mag1 mag2 mag3 mag4
4       100
```

I have insert value by following command

```
$final_q=  "INSERT INTO `subscription_complete` (`id`, `mag1`, `mag2`, `mag3`, `mag4`) VALUES ('".$row_q['id']."','".$row_q['mag1']."','".$row_q['mag2']."','".$row_q['mag3']."','".$row_q['mag4']."'
```

i want to update the subscription_complete table without replacing its value i.e.  100 for that i hvae write following query

```
$final_q1= "update subscription_complete set mag1='".$row_q['mag1']."',mag2='".$row_q['mag2']."',mag3='".$row_q['mag3']."',mag4='".$row_q['mag4']."' where id='".$row_q['id']."'";
```

can you tell me how to set 100 value in remaining column where the value is 0  ?

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: **WARNING**: Using manual escaping is extremely error prone and a single mistake can lead to a crippling [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Why not keep this on 1 table and use -1 or -100 as user does not have a subscription, 0 if pending and 100 if complete? Also can you show more of the php script. Surely all you have to do is update mag2 not input all pending into complete?

Comment: i am not able to distinguish between how to update what value so i have used update for entire table

Comment: i also tried for update in 0 0 0 0, 0 0 0 1, 0 0 1 0 ... like wise binary fashion for mag1 mag2 mag3 mag4  columns

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the empty fields in `subscription_pending` contain `NULL`, not empty strings.

```
UPDATE subscription_complete AS c
JOIN subscription_pending AS p ON p.id = c.id
SET c.mag1 = IFNULL(p.mag1, c.mag1),
    c.mag2 = IFNULL(p.mag2, c.mag2),
    c.mag3 = IFNULL(p.mag3, c.mag3),
    c.mag4 = IFNULL(p.mag4, c.mag4)
```

If they're actually empty strings, use `IF(p.magX = '', c.magX, p.magX)` instead of the `IFNULL` test.

Comment: i have tried both way but still not working means no updation take place